# Swift - Using a segue removes Top Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm using the performSegue function built into XCode to transfer between two views. I originally go from the view with the navigation bar to one without a navigation bar and it works perfectly. When I go back to the view with the Navigation Bar, the Bar just disappears and everything just moves up to fit the screen.

[image: This is how my Storyboard is set up]

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCameraSegue", sender: self)
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMainControllerSegue", sender: self)
```

I use these segues to transfer between the different views. I am also using a custom class to get the move the view from the right to left as design.

```
    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: If your segue setting in your storyboard is wrong, such things may happen. Please try to show how you setup your storyboard. And all relevant code, please.

Comment: @OOPer I updated the post!

Comment: Where is the code for _I go back to the view with the Navigation Bar_ ? As far as I can guess, you may be opening a new view controller, not going back to the same view controller. Do you understand that `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` is not a way to _go back_ ?

Comment: @OOPer Updated Again

Comment: @OOPer I think there is a problem with the custom class I use to animate the segue. If I don't use the custom animation, the navigation bar shows up. However I can't find what is wrong with animation

Comment: It may also be wrong but I cannot be sure as you are hiding the context. When you show your code, you should better show enough context - in what class and/or in what method the code exists, and how you bind the class to the actual segue...etc, etc.